# android error message from main.xml

Tags: android, xml

I am following an android tutorial it tells me to add this code to the main.xml file

```
    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height=height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is my first Android Application"/>
    <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="And this is a clickable button!/>
```

the main.xml file contains this text,  but when I add the above code to the bottom of the code below, it says "your code contains errors, please correct them and try again" What should I do?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in that code.

First TextView, remove the duplicated "=height" in layout_height:

```
<TextView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
android:text="This is my first Android Application"/>
```

On your button, you're not closing the quotes in android:text. See:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="And this is a clickable button!"/>
```

Finally, put all that before the closing tag of LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- put stuff here -->

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello" />

<!-- or here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what does this error message mean hh does not specify a android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner instrumentation or does not declare uses-library android.test.runner in its AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: That's another question. Ask a separate question for that. If this answer solves your layout problem, then click the gray tick (on the top left of my answer) to accept the answer I gave you and close this question (the tick will turn green). And then you go and ask another question. You should not ask two questions in the same topic, and as a reply to another answer. Best regards!

Comment: About your other question that was closed for being a duplicate: sorry, I'm not the one who decides this. Try posting the same question and tell that you looked at that and you still have the problem. That way the moderators will see that you researched but you still cannot solve your problem, thus avoiding it being closed for being a duplicated question. Try that...

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height=height="wrap_content"
```

Change to:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quotation mark:

```
android:text="And this is a clickable button!/>
```

fix:

```
android:text="And this is a clickable button!"/>
```